# Deploying Apollo Server 4 to Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to deploy the simplest of installs of Apollo/Server4 with Express on Firebase Functions. It's a modification of the simple example with Express from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@apollo/server.
When I deploy to the Google servers it fails with the following error:

> 36:15  error  A function with a name starting with an uppercase letter should only be used as a constructor  new-cap

this is the code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

import {ApolloServer} from "@apollo/server";
import {expressMiddleware} from "@apollo/server/express4";
import {ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer}
  from "@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer";
import http from "http";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  // The GraphQL schema
  const typeDefs = `#graphql
      type Query {
        hello: String
      }
    `;

  // A map of functions which return data for the schema.
  const resolvers = {
    Query: {
      hello: () => "world",
    },
  };

  const app = express();
  const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

  // Set up Apollo Server
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    plugins: [ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({httpServer})],   <--------line 36
  });
  server.start();

  app.use(
      cors(),
      bodyParser.json(),
      expressMiddleware(server),
  );
});

exports.graphql = functions.region("europe-west1").https.onRequest(app);
```

Is this a solvable issue or is it a bug?
TIA

Comment: Why you use require and then imports?

Comment: You're redeclaring the const `app` and both are `const`.